# What is the role of SEO for a new website compared to other marketing strategies?

Tags: seo, marketing

I am going to create new website and trying to earn money with it.

I am little confused.  Will proper SEO will help get high traffic levels for the site?  Will it also help the site earn money? Should I instead concentrate only on other marketing strategies? Do I need to use both SEO and other marketing?

I have also heard that we have to maintain SEO forever. Otherwise we will lose visitors and business. Is this true?

Comment: SEO doesn't make any money for your website.  You need to sell products or show ads for that to happen.

Comment: What is best for SEO changes from time to time, but the basics have been the same for 15 years:  Use text on your site that includes the keywords you want to rank for, make sure search engines can crawl your site, make sure your content is good enough that others find it useful and then recommend it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Thank you for answer and question edit.Sure I will follow your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO and marketing go hand in hand. I never really get to talk about it here, but much of what creates high CTR (click through rate) and high engagement for web users are marketing techniques that are typical Marketing 101 and not Internet related. As well, good ole fashioned marketing really boots a sites visibility especially for e-commerce and the service industry such as hotels, restaurants, etc. But it can also help in the tech sector and other areas too. I am talking about advertising. I once put out fliers in shop windows and that did the trick just fine. I still use an ad in the news paper each week where the website is listed. I know I get people who see the ad then check out the website before deciding to visit. People are more cautious these days until they get to know you. All you have to do is get them to your door (so to speak) and the rest is easy.

SEO is important for search visibility, but in my view, it is a mistake to think that the work is done at that point. I like what is called the *shot-gun approach*. You can take aim with one bullet and hit one target maybe or you can hit several geese with one shot. Your choice.